# How can I implement SSO between a web app and native app using IdentityServer?

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4

I’ve got a set of APIs written in ASP.NET. These are to be accessed by a web app and native mobile app, and should be protected by the SSO.

I would like to be able have a SSO, where the user can login online and access the web app, and can also login on the native app (via the browser), and it’ll remember their login details (ie with an authorization_token).

I’ve been looking into IdentityServer4 but I’m a bit stuck on which authorization flows I would need for this.

Any help is appreciated, as it’s starting to hurt my brain! Do let me know if I need to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flows, there are today only two flows you should consider.

- **Authorization code flow**, this flow is for clients where you want a user to login/signup, like a mobile app or web-application. Meaning, you have a user and a browser involved here.
- **Client credentials flow**, is all about machine to machine communication, where you have no user involved.

Comment: OAtuth 2.1 deprecated some of the flows (like implicit flow) so, what's left is only the two flows in my answer that they recommend.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now - I read about implicit flow but could really find out how to do it. Thanks for clearing that up!